# Why creating model classes on angular 2 since it works the same with javascript objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

what's the advantages of creating a class for each model object (eg. Employee, Company, School...) . Working with returned objects on the fly leads to the same result with less effort.

Answer (score 1):

Well following the class relations provides you all of the benefits which basic OOP provides you.

When application grows up and someone is just playing only with JS Object then it will be a huge mess. 
It's the same thing that why do we need Classes in OOP when we can do every thing by normal functional programs. We pass data to functions and get the values.

No let's take an easy example.

Let's say there are only 3 models **Employee** **Company** & **School**

Every model has it's own set of features like employee can have it's age , name and employee history. It has some methods to compute different stuff , like get Employee's average salary .

Same goes with other 2 models. All of these models can be linked to each other like Employee can belong to a company and Company can have multiple Employees.

So if we follow these relations then it's very easy to understand the app and manage it's behaviour.

But if you are dealing with only objects how will you manage these relations and transfer responsibilities to other models/classes.

I hope it can help you to understand it's huge benefits. 
There is looong list of OOP benefits

Comment: why nobody talks about this before angular 2. Everybody was happy with angular 1 even if it was dealing with fly JS objects